# Convert data from Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfoNoElement

Tags: arrays, powershell

When I do a `Get-Member` I get this class:

> TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfoNoElement

If I do a `$TS_Entries.Values` it only shows the `Name` column and no `Count` at all.

I have run a command that gives me exactly what I need.

```
$TS_Entries = $($TS_Entries | group -NoElement)
```

This generates the output below:

```
Count Name      
----- ----      
    2 FOAH574   
    1 FOAH652   
    1 FOAH704   
    1 FOAH787   
    1 PRJ0019835
    1 PRJ0031207
    1 PRJ0036053
    1 PRJ0031213
    3 FOAH18    
    1 FOAH519
```

I am trying to get this in to an array so I can multiply all the `Count` Values by 15.

```
Count Name      
----- ----      
   30 FOAH574   
   15 FOAH652   
   15 FOAH704   
   15 FOAH787   
   15 PRJ0019835
   15 PRJ0031207
   15 PRJ0036053
   15 PRJ0031213
   45 FOAH18    
   15 FOAH519
```

Comment: `... | select @{n='Count';e={15 * $_.Count}}, Name`?

Comment: You are a God send @Ansgar.  Thanks again man.